# Wordpress have_posts() is only returning one PAGE

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

i am trying to build a little wordpress website, and i've found myself stuck :

[image: my posts. I have 5 of them.]

I want to display my posts in a page, witht the loop :

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <!-- post title -->
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>
        <!-- /post title -->

    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Doing this in my page only returns me ONE element, which is also not even a post but a page

[image: result of the code above]

I was surprised, as this seem rather trivial. So i
wrote some code to debug this :

```
$a = get_posts();

echo("len : " . sizeof($a) . "<br/></br>");

foreach($a as $article){

    echo($article->post_title . "<br/>");
}
```

[image: result of above code]

Which to me makes absolutely no sense. I've been checking and trying things using examples and whatnot for the past hours, but to no avail....

EDIT 1 : In one sentence, the classic have_posts() loop only returns me ONE page instead of all posts

Thank you.

Comment: That is exactly as expected, it is how WP works - the loop in a standard WP page displays the content of that page. It doesn’t know you want it to display *other* posts instead unless you tell it! To tell the page which other posts you want to show, you use WP_Query and pass in the details for those posts. That is the correct behaviour, and that’s why your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found *a* solution :

```
$allPostsWPQuery = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
if ($allPostsWPQuery->have_posts()): while ($allPostsWPQuery->have_posts()) : $allPostsWPQuery->the_post(); ?>
```

replace the start of the loop block with this custom query

aaaaaand :

[image: result]

and don't forget to remove this custom query at the end `wp_reset_query();`

EDIT : Thanks to a comment, i know this is the expected behaviour.